# Data binding within an object and to the DOM

Tags: javascript, oop, data-binding

This is an extreme simplification of what I want to build(loan interest calculator). I have three fields. Whenever one field is changed, I want the others to change in order to satisfy this algebraic equation:

```
A = B * C
B = A / C
C = A / B
```

I think I want to bind these values with an object, but I'm not sure how to go about this. Here is the set up i have so far:

```
var binder = {
  a: 2,
  b: 1,
  c: 1
};

$('input[type=number]').on('change', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var value = id.val();
  binder[id] = Number($(this).val());    
});
```

At this point I've set the corresponding key in the object to the value of the currently active field. I could run through a bunch of `case()` statements like:

```
switch( id ) {
  case a :
    binder.b = $(this).val()/binder.c;
    binder.c = $(this).val()/binder.b;
    break;  
  etc.
}
```

I also need to update the field values. This seems unsustainable, especially when the number of fields grow, and the computation becomes more complex. My question is then twofold:

How do I bind the fields' values to the object?

How do I bind the object's values to each other?

Comment: There are a number of libraries that handle the plumbing for this sort of thing.  I'm a fan of Knockout.js, http://knockoutjs.com/, which uses ViewModels to bind to your DOM elements and supply the backing logic. Just build the objects you need to handle the calculations, and let KO deal with the binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dbugger commented [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) is perfect for this

```js
var model = {
  a: ko.observable(2),
  b: ko.observable(1),
  c: ko.observable(1)
};

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
A <input data-bind="value: a, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"> = (B x C) <span data-bind="text: b()*c()"></span><br />
B <input data-bind="value: b, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"> = (A / C) <span data-bind="text: a()/c()"></span><br />
C <input data-bind="value: c, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"> = (A / B) <span data-bind="text: a()/b()"></span><br />
```